# Why does std::make_shared<class T, class...Args>(Args&&... args) require T to have copy constructor?

Tags: c++11, make-shared

I don't understand why a class that has a deleted copy constructor (or contains a member, like ifstream, that has a deleted copy constructor and there it, too, has a  deleted copy constructor) can't be used with make_shared()?  This code shows what I'm talking about

```
class X {
 private:
     X(const X&) = delete;
     int x;
 public:
     X(int an_int)  : x{an_int} {};
     X() : x{10} {}
 };
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   // fails because X has no copy constructor 
   shared_ptr<X> ptr { make_shared<X>( X{8} ) };

   shared_ptr<X> ptr2 { new X{10} };// works fine

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a copy constructor because you are trying to construct a new X (in make shared) from an existing one, the temporary X{8}.

Comment: Also, deleting the copy constructor has probably implicitly deleted the move constructor so even though X{8} is an rvalue and could call the move constructor, it's not available.

Comment: `make_shared` takes the constructor parameters, not an existing instance, try just passing the 8, not X{8}.

Answer (score 7):

You may be missing the fact that `make_shared` will forward its arguments to the constructor of X. In this case you are passing `X{8}` as the constructor argument, so `make_shared` is forced to attempt copy or move construction.

In this particular example, deleting the copy constructor has implicitly deleted the move constructor, preventing construction from the temporary `X{8}`.

What you probably want to write is this:

```
shared_ptr<X> ptr { make_shared<X>(8) };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, that is what I wanted.